# Adding new keys/values to nested dictionary in geojson file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, geojson

I have a .js containing data used to plot points on a map. In the file, I have a single line var statement which contains nested dictionaries.

```
var json_Project = {"type":"FeatureCollection","name":"project","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}},"features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"ID":"001","field1":"someText","field2":"someText"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-1.14,60.15]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"ID":"002","field1":"someText","field2":"someText"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-1.14,60.15]}}]}
```

One of these contains the `"features"` key which stores a list of dictionaries for each point (see below for readability).

```
var json_Project = {"type":"FeatureCollection","name":"project","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}},"features":[
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"ID":"001","field1":"someText","field2":"someText"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-1.14,60.15]}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"ID":"002","field1":"someText","field2":"someText"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-1.14,60.15]}}]}
```

The `"properties"` for the first point has `"ID":"001"`, second point has `"ID":"001"` etc.

I would like to insert a new property for each point with `"INFORMATION:"` and get the value from another dictionary using the keys from `"ID"`.

```
info_dict = {'001': 'This is Project 1', 
             '002': 'This is Project 2'}
```

Specifically, I would like this new property to be inserted before `"field2"` so that it looks like:

```
var json_Project = {"type":"FeatureCollection","name":"project","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84"}},"features":[
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"ID":"001","field1":"someText","INFORMATION":"This is Project 1","field2":"someText"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-1.14,60.15]}},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"ID":"002","field1":"someText","INFORMATION":"This is Project 2","field2":"someText"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-1.14,60.15]}}]}
```

My futile attempt involved converting the one-liner to a string and then extract everything after the `"features:"` string as that is unique in the file. But not sure how to add the new key/value pair.

```
with open('project.js') as f:
    contents = f.read().split()
    contents_toString = ''.join(contents)
    new_contents = re.findall('(?<="features":\[).*$', contents_toString)
```

---

**EDIT**

Thanks to @TenaciousB, I can read the geojson file and add in the `"INFORMATION"` property with the correct values from the dictionary:

```
with open('project.js') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    x = json.loads(contents)
    for y in x['features']:
        key = y['properties']['ID']
        description = dictionary[key]
        y['properties']['INFORMATION'] = description
```

I am still unsure how to:

1. Remove `var json_Project =`  programmatically before being read;
2. Place the `"INFORMATION"` property before `"field2"`;
3. Re-insert `var json_Project =` , save and ensure the single-line format is retained.

Comment: Why are you using python to edit the contents a javascript file??? Why not just use javascript for this or use a json file? I'd go about this by reading the file as text and removing `var json_Project = ` and then `json.loads()` the string. Then you can work with it as a dictionary.

Comment: @TenaciousB I'm sorry, I started learning python and javascript not too long ago so I am not overly familiar with the best methods to solve this problem.

Comment: its all good, is the file created by you, or coming from somewhere else, and what are you going to use this data in after you add the items? Javascript or python?

Comment: @TenaciousB The file is created by QGIS plugin (https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web). There is an HTML file which loads the map and reads the data from the .js files. The plugin doesn't like it if a point on the map has more than 254 characters in a property value. So I want to get around that by inserting this information directly. It works manually but considering I have hundreds of points, I would like a more automated process. At the moment, I'm used to using Python.

Comment: I'm aware there is a GIS stack exchange but considering my question involves manipulation of code, I thought Stack Overflow might be the place to ask.